# How to secure and access a file for download in Android app

Tags: android, download

In order to download and save a file on the external SD card (could be a zip file with some media files or a database file),
what is the best practice of doing it?

How do I secure this zip file from public access on the web server?

How do I access the folder from the app in order to download the file?

Is it better to use Amazon S3 cloud storage or Google Cloud Storage and their APIs?

How usually the apps on the market secure and access their downloads?

Could anybody share sources and knowledge how can I do that, where I can find full documentation or which services I should use?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by secure. Is this paid for content that you don't want anyone to get for free, personal/private info or are there other reasons?

Comment: It could be paid or free content, but definitely don't want anyone who doesn't have the app to have access to the content. Just would like to know how is done on production apps, because I couldn't find any detailed info about it.
Mostly the reason is paid for content.